# Jquery actions on heroku stop working when heroku goes to sleep

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a ruby on rails app that runs on heroku (free tier). Everything works fine as long as the app is active, however, if the heroku app is left dormant for a while, it goes to sleep and the jquery actions start throwing timeout errors. All I need to do to fix it is refresh the page, but that isnt a very good user experience. Is there a way around this?

Thanks for your help!